# Unable to concatenate header string to write.table output in R

Tags: r

I am trying to concatenate a custom string to all the CSV files that I am generating like below.

```
myHeadTXT <- "Fixed format string
concatenation test."

# basepath = C:/temp (for example)
# Create directories
# for (p in unique(file.path(basepath, df$Grp, df$Subgrp))) dir.create(p, recursive = TRUE)

by(df, df$Subgrp, FUN=function(i, header, file) {
  cat(header = myHeadTXT, '\n',  file = file)
  write.csv(subset(i, select = -c(Grp, Subgrp)),
            file.path(basepath, i$Grp[1], i$Subgrp[1], "value.csv"),
            row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, append = TRUE)
})
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error in cat(header = myHeadTXT, "\n", file = file) : 
argument "file" is missing, with no default
```

Here is the sample data for code and error reproducibility.

```
Grp <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
Subgrp <- c("k", "l", "m", "n", "n", "n")
val1 <- c(1.1, 3.2, 4.5, 5.6, 6.7, 7.7)
df <- data.frame(Grp, Subgrp, val1)
```

My desired (sample) output in each `value.csv`:

```
Fixed format string
concatenation test.
val1
1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the question is about the anonymous function called by `by` not finding its argument `file`. It won't find `header` either, it is not passed to it.

- The first argument are the groups the data is split into.
- The extra arguments are passed after the function. In the case below I set a value for `header`.

As for the `file`, it is not a function argument, the function assembles it in its body.

There is another error, the use of `write.csv` with `append` set. From the documentation, my emphasis.

> `write.csv` and `write.csv2` provide convenience wrappers for writing CSV files. They set `sep` and `dec` (see below), `qmethod = "double"`, and `col.names` to NA if `row.names = TRUE` (the default) and to `TRUE` otherwise.
> [...]
> These wrappers are **deliberately inflexible**: they are designed to ensure that the correct conventions are used to write a valid file. **Attempts to change `append`, `col.names`, `sep`, `dec` or `qmethod` are ignored**, with a warning.

```
Grp <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
Subgrp <- c("k", "l", "m", "n", "n", "n")
val1 <- c(1.1, 3.2, 4.5, 5.6, 6.7, 7.7)
df <- data.frame(Grp, Subgrp, val1)

myHeadTXT <- "Fixed format string
concatenation test."

basepath <- "~/Temp"
# this variable tells what directories and
# files are to be deleted after testing the code
newdirs <- unique(file.path(basepath, df$Grp, df$Subgrp))

# Create directories
for (p in unique(file.path(basepath, df$Grp, df$Subgrp))) dir.create(p, recursive = TRUE)

by(df, df$Subgrp, FUN = function(i, header) {
  file <- file.path(basepath, i$Grp[1], i$Subgrp[1], "value.csv")
  cat(header, '\n',  file = file)
  write.table(
    subset(i, select = -c(Grp, Subgrp)),
    file = file,
    sep = ",",
    row.names = FALSE, 
    quote = FALSE, 
    append = TRUE
  )
}, header = myHeadTXT)
```